# Python 3.6 virtual env uses pip from python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment `SystemModeling`. I expect behavior like this:

```
(SystemModeling) Name-MacBook-Pro:thermofluids name$ pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /Users/name/.virtualenvs/SystemModeling/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

But instead, it appears to be using pip from a the python 2.7 in my system library:

```
(SystemModeling) Name-MacBook-Pro:thermofluids name$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

This is causing all kinds of issues when I try to use pip to do anything.

Comment: have you tried `pip3`?

Comment: To be sure your `pip` and `python` executables are pointing to the same environment, you can use `python -m pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is [shell command cache](https://ss64.com/bash/hash.html); you can clear the command cache using (bash, zsh)

```sh
hash -r
```

If that does not work, instead  of using `pip`, try `python -m pip` to force using pip installed for current environment's python executable.